# How to implement application wide variables

Tags: f#

I'm trying to implement a settings module in my app which should contain information about current state of application. For example, if the user opens some file I need to store the file name. Since I'm still learning F# I want to do it as functional a possible.

I know I should create a new value everytime I change something, but where do I store this value? It should be a singleton and since it's immutable I struggle with the solution.

How do I implement such "global variable"? Does it even play well within functional approach?

Comment: does global variable play well with functional programming? global variable does not play well with any programming !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just as it would within a function, with `let mutable` (used inside a module):

```
let mutable a = 4
a      // gets a
a <- 6 // sets a
```

Or, you could use a mutable object as a static member (this example uses a mutable reference cell):

```
type Settings =
    static member Filename = ref ""

Settings.Filename := "OpenMe.txt"
```

Global variables may be necessary sometimes, and this could be a viable use case, but they are considered dangerous. Values that change and influence a large portion of the program can make things rather unpredictable.

That said, in cases like yours, a single global variable can be a good solution. It could hold a record with the individual settings. I'd pay attention that any operations changing the global variable happen only when the program is in a well-defined state (i.e. not in the middle of a complicated operation) and guarantee that the variable's new value is sound.

Example:

```
type StateVariables =
    { Filename : string
      Opened : int }

module State =
    let mutable private cur = { Filename = ""; Opened = 0 }
    let get () = cur

    let openFile name =
        // ...
        cur <- { cur with Filename = name; Opened = cur.Opened + 1 }
```

Comment: @Vlad The question asks for a variable, which is imperative in nature. Theoretically, one could formulate the entire program as a kind of recursive function call, but that may raise issues with user interface libraries or performance (depending on the kind of program, compiler, UI tools). It is common to accept some imperative operations and use object-oriented techniques to encapsulate them. The program has variable state, but that state can only be altered via well-defined transactions, which are implemented in functional style.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a global variable in a module:

```
module Settings =
    let mutable FileName = ""

open Settings

FileName <- "foo"
```